# Disabling sectional navigation and leave bottom space free Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am using Warsaw theme, how to disable sectional navigation bar appears at the top of the slide in Warsaw theme, and also I want to keep blank space without any author's name and title name at the bottom of the each slides in Warsaw theme.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```